# css elements won't align right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this CSS:

```
#top-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  text-align:right;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width:100%;
}

#top-nav li {
  float: left;          
}

#top-nav #customer-login, #top-nav #reseller-login {
  border-right: 1px solid #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;  
}
#top-nav #reseller-login {
  border-right: 1px solid #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff;  
}

#top-nav #customer-login-trigger, #top-nav #reseller-login-trigger {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; 
}

#top-nav #customer-login-trigger, #top-nav #reseller-login-trigger {
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

#top-nav #customer-login-trigger:hover, #top-nav #reseller-login-trigger:hover,
#top-nav #login .active {
  background: #fff;
}

#top-nav #customer-login-content, #top-nav #reseller-login-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 0;
  text-align:left;
  z-index: 999;    
  background: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#eee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);  
  padding: 15px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
}

#top-nav li #customer-login-content, #top-nav li #reseller-login-content {
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;  
}

/*--------------------*/

#inputs input {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  width: 238px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset;
}

#inputs input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e8c291;
  outline: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;
}

/*--------------------*/

#login #actions {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#login #submit {        
  background-color: #d14545;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e97171), to(#d14545));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e97171, #d14545);
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;    
  border: 1px solid #7e1515;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
}

#login #submit:hover,
#login #submit:focus {      
  background-color: #e97171;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d14545), to(#e97171));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #d14545, #e97171);
}   

#login #submit:active {     
  outline: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;       
}

#login #submit::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}

#login label {
  float: right;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#login label input {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}
```

but i can't get the links to align right

here is a fiddle with the full code:

*http://jsfiddle.net/F7Kdy/*

Comment: Do you mean align "to the right", as is right aligned?

Comment: Just change the `float` property of `#top-nav li` to right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: This works but reverses the order of the `li`s. Use [Jay Harris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19620687/2280630).

You just need to set your `li`s to `float:right` like so:

```
#top-nav li {
  float: right; 
}
```

Even if their parent `ul` is set to `float: right`, they need to be set that way as well.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `float` attribute, since you are aligning it by the parent. And make sure the elements are inline with `display: inline-block`.

**Note:** if you add `float: right;`, you will change the order of the listed elements. thus making everything backwards.

```
#top-nav li {          
 display: inline-block;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jay_harris/F7Kdy/2/)

Comment: +1 You're absolutely right, and he doesn't need to switch the order around that way.

Answer (score 0):

Make the

```
#top-nav li {
 float: right;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7Kdy/1/)